# google sheets api : CORS Issue when copying sheets from one to another spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, cors, google-api-js-client

I am facing a quite irritating issue that I can't understand nor resolve. 
I am using google sheet api to retrieve (in order)
1. retrieve date from a spreadsheet 
2. updating this spreadsheet
3. creating a new spreadsheet using this data 
4. modifying this freshly created spreadsheet with a batchupdate
5. copying a sheet from another spreadsheet into this freshly created spreadsheet.

Everything works fine as it is, but I need to (5) before (4)ing so I can modify the added sheet in the same time.

BUT, when I do so, I'm getting an "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error.

First : Why is that ? It is not causing a probleme if 4 is before 5

Second : How can make use of CORS using google api call provided by this 'gapi' library ? 
Should I switch to some regular fetching/XMLHttp ? (which I can't do :s. )

Here is my code, please someone can review it and give me some advices.

```
    const createSpreadsheet = (type) => {

        type.toLowerCase()

        setDialogLoader({ open: true })

        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3')
            .then(() => {

                // 1.   getting current doc number

                let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                    spreadsheetId: config.configSpreadsheet.id,
                    range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                    valueRenderOption: 'FORMATTED_VALUE'
                })
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => { 

                // 2.    updating doc number

                console.log(resp)
                let number = parseInt(resp.result.values[0])
                let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
                    spreadsheetId: config.configSpreadsheet.id,
                    range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
                    resource: {
                        range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                        values: [[number + 1]],
                    },
                    includeValuesInResponse: true
                })
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => { 

                // 3.    creating the spreadsheet

                console.log(resp)
                let number = parseInt(resp.result.updatedData.values[0])
                let req = gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
                    'parents': [`${config.folderId[type]}`],
                    "name": type + '-' + number + '/' + selectedClient.nom,
                    "properties": {
                        type: type,
                        description: 'This is a resume of the tasks to do...',
                        date: Date.now(),
                        clientId: selectedClient.id,
                        number: number,
                    },
                    "fields": 'name, properties, id, webViewLink'
                })
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => { 

                // 4.   batchUpdate :modifying the sheet

                console.log(resp)
                if (type === 'devis') {
                    let newDevis = resp.result
                    setDevis([newDevis, ...devis])
                } else if (type === 'facture') {
                    let newFacture = resp.result
                    setFactures([newFacture, ...factures])
                }
                let params = {
                    spreadsheetId: resp.result.id
                }
                let batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
                    requests: requestBody
                };
                let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => { 

                // 5.   copying sheet from another SS ( CORS ISSUE IF before step 4 ??? )

                console.log(resp)
                var params = {
                    // The ID of the spreadsheet containing the sheet to copy.
                    spreadsheetId: '1_2Atry0sZ9MJ4VRMDRPC8cVIDWfOnC_k66HYKXfdfS0',
                    // The ID of the sheet to copy.
                    sheetId: 0,
                }
                var copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
                    // The ID of the spreadsheet to copy the sheet to.
                    destinationSpreadsheetId: resp.result.spreadsheetId,
                    // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
                };
                var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(params, copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody);
                return request
            })
            .then((resp) => setDialogLoader({ open: false }))
            .then((resp) => setSnackbarObject({
                open: true,
                message: type === 'devis' ?
                    `Un devis vient d'être créé dans votre dossier 'Devis` :
                    `Une facture vient d'être créée dans votre dossier 'Factures`
            }))
            .then((resp) => setDocChooserObj({ open: false }))
            .catch(reason => {
                console.log(reason)
            })
    }
```

Now here is the code with the 5 before the 4.

```
    const createSpreadsheet = (type) => {

        type.toLowerCase()

        setDialogLoader({ open: true })

        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3')
            .then(() => {

                // 1.   getting current doc number

                let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                    spreadsheetId: config.configSpreadsheet.id,
                    range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                    valueRenderOption: 'FORMATTED_VALUE'
                })
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => {

                // 2.    updating doc number

                console.log(resp)
                let number = parseInt(resp.result.values[0])
                let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
                    spreadsheetId: config.configSpreadsheet.id,
                    range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
                    resource: {
                        range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                        values: [[number + 1]],
                    },
                    includeValuesInResponse: true
                })
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => {

                // 3.    creating the spreadsheet

                console.log(resp)
                let number = parseInt(resp.result.updatedData.values[0])
                let req = gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
                    'parents': [`${config.folderId[type]}`],
                    "name": type + '-' + number + '/' + selectedClient.nom,
                    "properties": {
                        type: type,
                        description: 'This is a resume of the tasks to do...',
                        date: Date.now(),
                        clientId: selectedClient.id,
                        number: number,
                    },
                    "fields": 'name, properties, id, webViewLink'
                })
                return req
            })
            .then(resp => {

                // 5.   copying sheet from another SS ( CORS ISSUE IF before step 4 ??? )

                console.log(resp)
                var params = {
                    // The ID of the spreadsheet containing the sheet to copy.
                    spreadsheetId: '1_2Atry0sZ9MJ4VRMDRPC8cVIDWfOnC_k66HYKXfdfS0',
                    // The ID of the sheet to copy.
                    sheetId: 0,
                }
                var copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
                    // The ID of the spreadsheet to copy the sheet to.
                    destinationSpreadsheetId: resp.result.id,
                    // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
                };
                var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(params, copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody);
                return request
            })
            .then(resp => {

                // 4.   batchUpdate :modifying the sheet

                console.log(resp)
                if (type === 'devis') {
                    let newDevis = resp.result
                    setDevis([newDevis, ...devis])
                } else if (type === 'facture') {
                    let newFacture = resp.result
                    setFactures([newFacture, ...factures])
                }
                let params = {
                    spreadsheetId: resp.result.spreadsheetId
                }
                let batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
                    requests: requestBody
                };
                let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)
                return req
            })
            .then((resp) => { console.log(resp); setDialogLoader({ open: false })})
            .then((resp) => setSnackbarObject({
                open: true,
                message: type === 'devis' ?
                    `Un devis vient d'être créé dans votre dossier 'Devis` :
                    `Une facture vient d'être créée dans votre dossier 'Factures`
            }))
            .then((resp) => setDocChooserObj({ open: false }))
            .catch(reason => {
                console.log(reason)
            })
    }
```

And the exact error message I get

```
Access to fetch at 'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.fr.HrYtnuOsJ9o.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOM4asNhhVgOFJKHWvKD0xkG7mu1Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

and then this ...

>
index.js:1 GET [https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.fr.HrYtnuOsJ9o.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOM4asNhhVgOFJKHWvKD0xkG7mu1Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.fr.HrYtnuOsJ9o.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOM4asNhhVgOFJKHWvKD0xkG7mu1Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0) net::ERR_FAILED

Here is the requestBody (batchUpdate)

```
let setWidthRequest = {
    "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "range": {
            "dimension": "COLUMNS",
            "startIndex": 1,
            "endIndex": 2
        },
        "properties": {
            "pixelSize": 500 // 575 before new column has been added
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
    }
}

let setWidthRequest2 = {
    "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "range": {
            "dimension": "COLUMNS",
            "startIndex": 1,
            "endIndex": 3
        },
        "properties": {
            "pixelSize": 75
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
    }
}

//Keep only 3 columns
let deleteColumnsRequest = {
    "deleteDimension": {
        "range": {
            "dimension": "COLUMNS",
            "endIndex": 30,
            "startIndex": 5
        }
    }
}

// add cool formula to each cell
let prodFormulaRequest = {
    "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "startColumnIndex": 4,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 4,
            "endRowIndex": 1000
        },
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredValue": {
                "formulaValue": "=IF(ISBLANK(C1);;C1*D1)"
            }
        },
        "fields": "*"
    }
}

let freezeRequest = {
    "updateSheetProperties": {
        "properties": {
            "gridProperties": {
                "frozenRowCount": 1
            }
        },
        "fields": "gridProperties.frozenRowCount"
    }
}

let addTitleRequest = {
    "updateCells": {
        "fields": "*",
        "range": {
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 5,
            "endRowIndex": 1
        },
        "rows": [
            {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "Ref"
                        },
                        "textFormatRuns": [
                            {
                                "format": {
                                    "bold": true
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "effectiveFormat": {
                            "backgroundColor": {
                                "blue": 1
                            },
                            "verticalAlignment": "TOP"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "Description"
                        },
                        "textFormatRuns": [
                            {
                                "format": {
                                    "bold": true
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "effectiveFormat": {
                            "backgroundColor": {
                                "blue": 1
                            },
                            "verticalAlignment": "TOP"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "Quantité",
                        },
                        "textFormatRuns": [
                            {
                                "format": {
                                    "bold": true
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "effectiveFormat": {
                            "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                            "backgroundColor": {
                                "blue": 1
                            },
                            "verticalAlignment": "TOP"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "Prix Unitaire"
                        },
                        "textFormatRuns": [
                            {
                                "format": {
                                    "bold": true
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "effectiveFormat": {
                            "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                            "backgroundColor": {
                                "blue": 1
                            },
                            "verticalAlignment": "TOP"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": {
                            "stringValue": "Montant"
                        },
                        "textFormatRuns": [
                            {
                                "format": {
                                    "bold": true
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "effectiveFormat": {
                            "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                            "backgroundColor": {
                                "blue": 1
                            },
                            "verticalAlignment": "TOP"
                        }
                    },

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

let protectionRangeRequest1 = {
    "addProtectedRange": {
        "protectedRange": {
            "range": {
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 1,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endColumnIndex": 10
            },
            "description": "no touch",
            "warningOnly": true
        },

    }
}

let protectionRangeRequest2 = {
    "addProtectedRange": {
        "protectedRange": {
            "range": {
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 1000,
                "startColumnIndex": 3,
                "endColumnIndex": 4
            },
            "description": "no touch",
            "warningOnly": true
        },
    }
}

let numberFormatRequest = {
    "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": 1000,
            "startColumnIndex": 1,
            "endColumnIndex": 4
        },
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
                "numberFormat": {
                    "type": "NUMBER",
                    "pattern": "####.00"
                }
            }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
    }
}

let dataValidation = {

    "setDataValidation": {
        "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 1,
            "endRowIndex": 1000,
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 1
        },
        "rule": {
            "condition": {
                "type": "ONE_OF_RANGE",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "userEnteredValue": "=\'Copie de liste\'!A1:A17"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputMessage": "Choose some, son of a bitch !",
            "strict": true,
            "showCustomUi": true
        }
    }
}

export let requestBody = [
    deleteColumnsRequest,
    prodFormulaRequest,
    setWidthRequest,
    addTitleRequest,
    freezeRequest,
    protectionRangeRequest1,
    protectionRangeRequest2,
    numberFormatRequest,
    // metaRequest
]
```

Comment: In your current script in your question, it seems that the order is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Can you provide the script by the order of 1, 2, 3, 5 and 4 for replicating your issue?

Comment: When you get that *"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"* error, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Comment: Thank you guys. Please have a look at my question as I edited it. Thank you

Comment: and http status code is 'failed'

Comment: The response from `https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.fr.HrYtnuOsJ9o.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=wQE/rs=AGLTcCOM4asNhhVgOFJKHWvKD0xkG7mu1Q/cb=gapi.loaded_0` is a 200 OK but doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. That means it’s not CORS-enabled, and there’s nothing you can do from your frontend code to fix it. It’s not intended to be called from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. You need to make the request from your backend code instead.

Comment: Can you explain why it works the other way around ?

Comment: @user1859295 Thank you for adding the information. I noticed your updated question just now. Can I ask you about `requestBody` of `let batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {requests: requestBody}`? I cannot find the value of `requestBody` in your script.

Comment: requestBody is a big batch of 8 edit requests. I edit the question so you can see them. Those are in a separate file.

Comment: OK. I am pretty sure I know now what is going on. Back from the creation of the new sheet, the response in the promise is not returning any spreadsheetId but do return a sheetID. ID I am using for the destinationSpreadsheetId in the next request. I guess this unique ID send me to another spreadsheet NOT owned by me.

Comment: I am sorry if I wasted your time guys. But as long as you're here. Do you guys know if I can get the spreadsheetId back from a spreadsheets.sheets.copyto request ?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Dear, Tanaike. Thank you for your time. In the meanwhile, I worked on my script and came with an other solution (I would say even cleaner). As soon as I understood that I needed the response of those 2 last requests, I tried to return the request AND the spreadsheetId from previous request but I am not really good at promises. So couldn't figure it out. Now I guess this is exactly how to do (cf. your script) (So you can return an array from a promise ? Good to know. You can't return an object, can you ?

Comment: I will post my script as soon as possible

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to know the reason that the order of 1, 2, 3, 5 and 4 occurs an error, while the order of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 occurs no error.

  - The requests of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are as follows.

    1. `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get`
    2. `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update`
    3. `gapi.client.drive.files.create`
    4. `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate`
    5. `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo`
- You want to achieve your goal using gapi with JavaScript.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API, and also you can create a file using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

I think that the reason of your issue is due to that `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo` returns no Spreadsheet ID. I think that this might be the specification at Google side. In your script, you use the Spreadsheet ID retrieved from each request. In this case, when the Spreadsheet ID is not returned, an error occurs. When the order is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, the method of "sheets.copyTo" is the last request. By this, no error occurs. On the other hand, when the order is 1, 2, 3, 5 and 4, the method of "batchUpdate" is run after the method of "sheets.copyTo" is run. In this case, the method of "sheets.copyTo" returns no Spreadsheet ID. By this, an error occurs. I think that this brings your error.

Under the order of 1, 2, 3, 5 and 4, in order to avoid the error, I would like to propose to return both the response from `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo` and the Spreadsheet ID.

From your additional `requestBody`, I could understand that the structure of `requestBody` is correct.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
.then(resp => {

    // 5.   copying sheet from another SS ( CORS ISSUE IF before step 4 ??? )

    console.log(resp)
    var params = {
        // The ID of the spreadsheet containing the sheet to copy.
        spreadsheetId: '1_2Atry0sZ9MJ4VRMDRPC8cVIDWfOnC_k66HYKXfdfS0',
        // The ID of the sheet to copy.
        sheetId: 0,
    }
    var copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
        // The ID of the spreadsheet to copy the sheet to.
        destinationSpreadsheetId: resp.result.id,
        // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
    };
    var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(params, copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody);
    return request
})
.then(resp => {

    // 4.   batchUpdate :modifying the sheet

    console.log(resp)
    if (type === 'devis') {
        let newDevis = resp.result
        setDevis([newDevis, ...devis])
    } else if (type === 'facture') {
        let newFacture = resp.result
        setFactures([newFacture, ...factures])
    }
    let params = {
        spreadsheetId: resp.result.spreadsheetId
    }
    let batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
        requests: requestBody
    };
    let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)
    return req
})
```

#### To:

```
.then(resp => {

    // 5.   copying sheet from another SS ( CORS ISSUE IF before step 4 ??? )

    console.log(resp)
    var params = {
        // The ID of the spreadsheet containing the sheet to copy.
        spreadsheetId: '1_2Atry0sZ9MJ4VRMDRPC8cVIDWfOnC_k66HYKXfdfS0',
        // The ID of the sheet to copy.
        sheetId: 0,
    }
    var copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
        // The ID of the spreadsheet to copy the sheet to.
        destinationSpreadsheetId: resp.result.id,
        // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
    };
    var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(params, copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody);
    return [request, resp.result.id];  // <--- Modified
})
.then(([resp, spreadsheetId]) => {  // <--- Modified

    // 4.   batchUpdate :modifying the sheet

    console.log(resp)
    if (type === 'devis') {
        let newDevis = resp.result
        setDevis([newDevis, ...devis])
    } else if (type === 'facture') {
        let newFacture = resp.result
        setFactures([newFacture, ...factures])
    }
    let params = {
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId  // <--- Modified
    }
    let batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
        requests: requestBody
    };
    let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)
    return req
})
```

### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `requestBody` has already been given.

### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 
thank you to Tanaike who took some time to think about my problem and propose a solution, which I selected as accepted solution.

Of course, the problem was that the ID of the spreadsheet was false, and so the request pointed to a spreadsheet that does not exist. This is why the CORS alert came.

Here is my version. Not sure if it is better or not, just a bit different.

```
const createSpreadsheet = (type) => {

        type.toLowerCase()

        setDialogLoader({ open: true })

        let load = gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3')

        let getNumber = () => {
            let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                spreadsheetId: config.configSpreadsheet.id,
                range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                valueRenderOption: 'FORMATTED_VALUE'
            })
            return req
        }

        let updateNumber = (resp) => {
            let number = parseInt(resp.result.values[0])
            let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
                spreadsheetId: config.configSpreadsheet.id,
                range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                valueInputOption: 'RAW',
                resource: {
                    range: config.configSpreadsheet.range[type],
                    values: [[number + 1]],
                },
                includeValuesInResponse: true
            })
            return req
        }

        let createSpreadsheet = (resp) => {
            let number = parseInt(resp.result.updatedData.values[0])
            let req = gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
                'parents': [`${config.folderId[type]}`],
                "name": type + '-' + number + '/' + selectedClient.nom,
                "properties": {
                    type: type,
                    description: 'This is a resume of the tasks to do...',
                    date: Date.now(),
                    clientId: selectedClient.id,
                    number: number,
                },
                "fields": 'name, properties, id, webViewLink'
            })
            return req
        }

        let copyTo = (resp) => {
            console.log(resp)
            var params = {
                // The ID of the spreadsheet containing the sheet to copy.
                spreadsheetId: '1_2Atry0sZ9MJ4VRMDRPC8cVIDWfOnC_k66HYKXfdfS0',
                // The ID of the sheet to copy.
                sheetId: 0,
            }
            var copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody = {
                // The ID of the spreadsheet to copy the sheet to.
                destinationSpreadsheetId: resp.result.id,
                // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
            };
            var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo(params, copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheetRequestBody);
            return request
        }

        let batchUpdate = (resp) => {
            console.log(resp)

            let spreadsheetId = resp[0]
            let sheetId = resp[1]

            console.log(spreadsheetId)
            console.log(sheetId)

            let params = {
                spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId
            }
            let batchUpdateValuesRequestBody = {
                requests: requestBody(sheetId)
            };
            let req = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)
            return req
        }

        let a = load
            .then(() => getNumber())
            .then(resp => updateNumber(resp))
            .then(resp => createSpreadsheet(resp))
            .then(resp => {
                let type = resp.result.properties.type
                if (type === 'devis') {
                    let newDevis = resp.result
                    setDevis([newDevis, ...devis])
                } else if (type === 'facture') {
                    let newFacture = resp.result
                    setFactures([newFacture, ...factures])
                }
                return resp
            })

        let b = a.then(resp => copyTo(resp))

        return Promise.all([a, b])
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp)
                let spreadsheetId = resp[0].result.id
                let sheetId = resp[1].result.sheetId
                return batchUpdate([spreadsheetId, sheetId])
            })
            .then(resp => {
                setDialogLoader({ open: false })
                setSnackbarObject({
                    open: true,
                    message: type === 'devis' ?
                        `Un devis vient d'être créé dans votre dossier 'Devis` :
                        `Une facture vient d'être créée dans votre dossier 'Factures`
                })
                setDocChooserObj({ open: false })
            })
            .then(resp => console.log(resp))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```